# Acumatica Report Designer, Tables are connected but data are not displayed

Tags: report, field, acumatica

Anyone who knows Acumatica? Please I need help on this.

I'm trying to display the Department of the salesperson in my SO summary report.

I joined SOOrder and EPEmployee with salespersonid. There is no error that tells me there wasn't that table so I assume I ain't wrong in schema. But there's no data display from EPEmployee table. What should I do? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You could try running request profiler in Acumatica to see if it can provide the generated SQL or any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mark Sales Person as Employee in Employee Screen? Refer to the below screenshot for the mapping we are referring to.

[image: Employee_Screenshot]

Also, if you have already done the above mapping, can you check if your SOorder has SalesPersonID in it?

We think you need to put a relationship between SOline and EPEmployee with SalesPersonID to handle the scenario where a Sales Order has multiple salespersons.